# How to add mapping entries of all records between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables **city**, **product** and **product_city_mapping**.

In product table I have around **500** records and I need to create mapping of each `product` record with `city` by the use of `product_city_mapping`.

Is there any way by which I can write a SQL query in MySQL which creates records for me in `product_city_mapping`?

I need to add entries in `product_city_mapping` for all product rows and `CityId` as **1**.
E.g., in `product_city_mapping` in need records like this:

```
Id    CityId    ProductId
1     1         101
2     1         102
3     1         103
4     1         104
..    ..        ...
```

[image: Table description]

Comment: what you tried so far ??

Comment: [INSERT INTO product_city_mapping (productid,cityid)] `SELECT p.id,c.id FROM product p,city c;` ???

Comment: I have to put one by one so searching a way to do this in single query

Comment: Before you build the mapping table, how do you know that Product 101 is in City 1?

Comment: City is new requirement, previously all products belong to only one city and now client looking to add one more city, that is why city and product_city_mapping has been introduced. So i am mapping all previous product to city=1.